# Can the uniform id be changed from run to run on the same machine?

Tags: opengl, shader, android

I have a shader which has several uniform variables:

```
uniform vec4 a;
uniform vec4 b;
uniform vec4 c;
```

I'm getting these handles using `glGetUniformLocation()` and storing them in the array. The game was suspended, then resumed and [onSurfaceCreated()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.Renderer.html) has been called. The question is: whether these handles will be valid or I need to re-get them using `glGetUniformLocation()` once again?

Comment: Related: [Do I need to rebind uniforms or attributes when changing shader programs?](http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/305/127)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The uniform locations are set when the program is linked and are tied to the program.

This means that when you create a new program then the uniform locations can change.